# Getting AttributeError: module 'base64' has no attribute 'decodestring' error while running on python 3.9.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, ldif

Issue description:

Getting `AttributeError: module 'base64' has no attribute 'decodestring'` error while running on python 3.9.6

Steps to reproduce:

Below is a dummy program, while running on python 3.9.6, I am getting `AttributeError: module 'base64' has no attribute 'decodestring'`` error:

```
from ldif3 import LDIFParser

parser = LDIFParser(open('dse3.ldif', 'rb'))
for dn, entry in parser.parse():
    if dn == "cn=Schema Compatibility,cn=plugins,cn=config":
        if entry['nsslapd-pluginEnabled'] == ['on']:
            print('Entry record: %s' % dn)
```

Error message:

```
python3.9 1.py                              ✔    venvpy3.9   11:12:01 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rasrivas/local_test/1.py", line 4, in <module>
    for dn, entry in parser.parse():
  File "/Users/rasrivas/local_test/venvpy3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ldif3.py", line 384, in parse
    yield self._parse_entry_record(block)
  File "/Users/rasrivas/local_test/venvpy3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ldif3.py", line 357, in _parse_entry_record
    attr_type, attr_value = self._parse_attr(line)
  File "/Users/rasrivas/local_test/venvpy3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ldif3.py", line 315, in _parse_attr
    attr_value = base64.decodestring(line[colon_pos + 2:])
AttributeError: module 'base64' has no attribute 'decodestring'
```

python version

```
python --version 
Python 3.9.6
```

Operating system:

macOS 11.5.2

Python version:

```
python --version 
Python 3.9.6
```

python-ldap version:

`ldif3-3.2.2`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [docs for Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/base64.html#base64.decodestring), `base64.decodestring()` is described as a:

> Deprecated alias of decodebytes().

It looks like the `base64.decodestring()` function has been deprecated since Python 3.1, and removed in Python 3.9. You will want to use the `bas64.decodebytes()` function instead.

Comment: Hi @BillyBBone, I happen to get the same error, just with encoding instead of decoding a string, and it doesn't let me change that to bytes instead of string. I get the below error - 

"TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Answer (score 6):

`decodestring()` no longer exists from v 3.9. Checkout this docs, use [base64.decodebytes()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/base64.html#base64.decodebytes) instead

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post but I am leaving here in case someone stumbles upon the same question.

To decode base64 to bytes use `base64.b64decode()`

You can find more info [here](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/base64.html)

Answer (score -3):

Try install base64 in your python, use the command:

```
pip install pybase64
```

or:

```
pip3 install pybase64
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but still I am getting the same error: `pip3 install pybase64 --> Requirement already satisfied: pybase64 in ./venvpy3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.2.0)` ==> error message `AttributeError: module 'base64' has no attribute 'decodestring'`